# posting hidden value

Tags: php, forms, hidden

hey there,
i have three pages:
(1) bookingfacilities.php
(2) booking_now.php
(3) successfulbooking.php
and they are link together.

i want to pass data from bookingfacilities.php to successfulbooking.php by using hidden field/value. however, my data doesn't get print out in successfulbooking.php.

here are my codes:

- from 'booking_now.php':
  `$date="$day-$month-$year";`
- from 'successfulbooking.php';
  `<input type="hidden" name="date" id="hiddenField" value="<?php print "$date" ?>"/>`

i would greatly appreciate your help as my project is due tomorrow :(

Answer (score 11):

You should never assume `register_global_variables` is turned on. Even if it is, it's deprecated and you should never use it that way.

Refer directly to the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables. Most likely your form is POSTing, so you'd want your code to look something along the lines of this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="hiddenField" value="<?php echo $_POST['date'] ?>" />
```

If this doesn't work for you right away, print out the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable on the page that would have the hidden form field and determine exactly what you want and refer to it.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: is it right at the first page - booking facilities.php, i will need to add a hidden field function too?!

Answer (score 9):

Maybe a little late to the party but why don't you use sessions to store your data?

bookingfacilities.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['form_date'] = $date;
```

successfulbooking.php

```
session_start();
$date = $_SESSION['form_date'];
```

Nobody will see this.

Comment: Great idea, actually. There's no reason to use Get and Post data when you can simply use Sessions instead.

Comment: This is the best solution. I use session variables when I need data to persist through several pages. If not then you have to have inputs on every page to post the data again and again. Additionally, the variable used is "booking_now"... if it is NOW then why not use PHP's date() method. As in: $today = date("m-d-Y");

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `$_POST['date']` instead of `$date` if it's coming from a POST request ($_GET if it's a GET request).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you just did there, but from what I can tell this is what you're asking for:

bookingfacilities.php

```
<form action="successfulbooking.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>">  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

successfulbooking.php

```
<?php
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    // add code here
?>
```

Not sure what you want to do with that third page(booking_now.php) too.